# Access-Control-Allow-Origin after adding meteor-velocity

Tags: meteor, meteor-velocity

I have a meteor application that uses google maps.

After I added jasmine and velocity:html-reporter as dependencies the following error keeps coming at the moment google maps is loaded:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource...

Can anyone give me a hint whats going on and how i can fix it?

Add: `velocity_source-map-support.js:90` this is the error line

Comment: Are you using the `BrowserPolicy` package?

Comment: No i am not using `BrowserPolicy`. Also if I remove jasmine and velocity the error is gone.

Comment: This is apparently a [known bug in chimp](https://github.com/xolvio/chimp/issues/98) that doesn't have a resolution yet.

Comment: ok thx for help. kind of a bummer that you cannot easily test apps with gmaps included...

Comment: What if you added BrowserPolicy and then set it up to allow access to gmaps? BrowserPolicy is worth installing anyway.

Comment: I tried various BrowserPolicy setups now. Still no luck. How would the config look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96058/discussion-between-michel-floyd-and-littlestudent).